# Grails : Error saving object, hard to understand, don't use 'property' keyword

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails, save, stack-trace

I get a domain class like that :

```
class Offer {

    Property property
    Building building
    ExternalSystem externalSystem
    OfferStatus status
    Double offerPrice
    String currency
    String description
    String adventages
    Date offerDisponibility
    OfferNature offerNature
    Surfaces surfaces

    static hasMany = [units: Unit]

    static constraints = {
        building nullable: true
        externalSystem nullable: true
        description nullable: true
        adventages nullable: true
    }
}
```

When populating it into a controller :

```
def offer = new Offer()
offer.property = Property.get(1)
offer.building = Building.get(1)
offer.externalSystem = ExternalSystem.get(1)
offer.status = OfferStatus.get(1)
offer.offerPrice = 26860
offer.currency = 'EUR'
offer.description = 'WONDERFULL OFFER !'
offer.offerDisponibility = convertDate('12/04/2014')
offer.offerNature = OfferNature.read(1)
offer.surfaces = Surfaces.get(2)
offer.validate()
```

I get a strange behaviour when validating, saving or whatever on this object.
It is the only domain object domain wich do that.

I get two different stacktrace, tha's the most strange part of my problem, the first stacktrace apear when I'm calling my controller the first time :

```
| Error 2013-11-26 11:27:10,971 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing
 request: [GET] /Project/login/auth
0. Stacktrace follows:
Message: 0
    Line | Method
->>  116 | doCall    in com.project.security.LoginController$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

The second is alway the last stacktrace :

```
| Error 2013-11-26 11:01:43,704 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR [/Project].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Project] threw exception [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.lang.Math.max() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, null) values: [4, null]
Possible solutions: max(int, int), max(double, double), max(float, float), max(long, long), min(int, int), wait()] with root cause
Message: No signature of method: static java.lang.Math.max() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, null) values: [4, null]
Possible solutions: max(int, int), max(double, double), max(float, float), max(long, long), min(int, int), wait()
    Line | Method
->>  251 | doAppend              in org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     66 | appendLoopOnAppenders in org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl
|    206 | callAppenders . . . . in org.apache.log4j.Category
|    391 | forcedLog             in     ''
|    856 | log . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    192 | logMessage            in org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter
|    167 | error . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    213 | error                 in org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog
|    200 | doFilter . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

So which stacktrace is the correct ?

How can I solve this ?

No stacktrace if I'm not calling save() or validate() message.

**Adding failOnError: true did not change the stacktrace.**

Making :

```
if (!offer.save()) {
    log.error offer.errors
}
```

did not change the stacktrace.

Thanks for reading,

Snite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of research, I finally solve my issue.

```
Property myProperty
```

Don't know why, but 'property' as variable name (and not domain class name) seems to be a reserved keyword...

Hope it will be usefull.

Comment: I spent 2 days head scracthiing until I realised, I had a variable named Property. Changed to theProperty. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is wrong and and what was blocking .

Ok, editing my classes, I see that is a problem about abstract class.

Remember my Offer class :

```
class Offer {

//  Property property
    Building building
    ExternalSystem externalSystem
    OfferStatus status
    Double offerPrice
    String currency
    String description
    String adventages
    Date offerDisponibility
    OfferNature offerNature
    Surfaces surfaces

    static hasMany = [units: Unit]

    static constraints = {
        building nullable: true
        externalSystem nullable: true
        description nullable: true
        adventages nullable: true
    }
}
```

Commenting out the  (Member Variable of the above class ) Property solve my problem.

Here is my Property class :

```
class Property extends Content {

    AssetManager assetManager
    Owner owner
    Mandat mandat
    AddressContent addressContent

    static hasMany = [
        buildings: Building,
        propertyMandats: PropertyMandat
    ]

    static constraints = {
        assetManager nullable: true
        mandat nullable: true
        owner nullable: true
    }
}
```

And here is my Content class :

```
abstract class Content {

    String name
    ExternalSystem externalSystem

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: true
        externalSystem nullable: true
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { name }

}
```

Hibernate does not generate any 'property' table, but the 'content' table is like that after a desc :

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version             | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| external_system_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| class               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sys_admin_client_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| is_public_offer     | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| public_offer        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fund_id             | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address_content_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| asset_manager_id    | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| mandat_id           | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| owner_id            | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_name           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mail                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_number1       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_number2       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| agency_id           | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| begin_date          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| client_owner_id     | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_date            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mandat_number       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My Content class extends lot of classes.

So, I suppose the problem is about the fact no 'property' table is created.

Why this behavior?
And is this something wrong about my content abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

About your question of the `content` table,

"At the database level Grails by default uses `table-per-hierarchy` mapping with a discriminator column called `class` so the parent class (Content) and its subclasses (BlogEntry, Book etc.), share the same table."

The Grails Framework-Reference Documentation-7.2.3 Inheritance in GORM

Hope this helps.